# What information should I log if I detect that my site is under attack?

Tags: security, logging

In the code below if I get into the `if` statement I can safely say my site is under attack.  What information is it a good idea to log?
Any recommendations on actions that can be taken to minimize the damage at this point?

```
protected void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(tb_SearchBox.Text.Length > tb_SearchBox.MaxLength)
   {
      //What should i log?
      //What actions should I take?
   }
   //Otherwise search
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the action I would just redirect them to error page.

For the logging I would do as @The Rook mentioned and grab the entire request. I would use some logging software, such as [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). ELMAH captures the entire HTTP Request as well as referrer IP. Logging is good regardless of security concerns

Comment: Why not tell them you're onto them in the hopes of scaring them off?

Comment: More than likely it will be an automated attack, so a real person will not see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can log the ip and log how many times he has already attempted to hack you. If it's above a certain threshhold you can block his ip for a certain amount of time

Answer (score 1):

When a Web application firewall like [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) detects an attack it will log the entire HTTP request, along with the remote IP address.